# Google play console: I get an error trying to verify myself

Tags: google-play-console

I tried to verify myself in Google Play Console and the default country was set to United States when filling in address but I am from Slovakia. I went to Payments profile in google wallet and there I had two profiles, one with the country of Slovakia and the other set to USA. I "closed" (deleted) the profile with the USA country, and returned to verify my identity in Google Play console and now I get an error message

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (5D1AB983)

I tried deleting cookies and it didn't work. What should I do? I want to verify myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted Payments profile with a different country in it you need to contact Google Play Console support with a request to delete your Play Console account. Money will be returned and then you create your account again and the problem should be solved. Then I verified myself. That's how I solved this problem.